# Get a list of all Office 365 Groups with creation date

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

I am currently using the following script to pull a list of all my Office 365 groups.

```
Get-sposite -Limit All | Where {$_.Template -like "GROUP#0"} | Select URL,Title,StorageQuota,StorageUsageCurrent,Template,Status | Export-Csv C:\Support\Output\GroupSites-$date.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I am trying to add creation date or last modified date to the report, could anyone assist me with what objects need to be added in the select options to get those?

Answer (score 2):

First I'll answer your question, and then I'll teach you how to find these properties for your self.

Just add the LastContentModifiedDate to your list of properties

```
Get-sposite -Limit All | Where {$_.Template -like "GROUP#0"} | Select URL,Title,LastContentModifiedDate,StorageQuota,StorageUsageCurrent,Template,Status
```

Now, to find these properties for yourself, load your script in PowerShell ISE, loop through the results, and stick a breakpoint on the $_ iterator.

[image]

There does not seem to be a Created Date on the object so you'll have to live with this one. Also, be careful with modified dates on site objects. They might return false positives, for example a platform update might trigger a modified event.